# Pandas find and replace based on column items count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd

all_data_set = [
        ('A','Area1','AA','A B D E','A B','D E'),
        ('B','Area1','AA','A B D E','A B','D E'),
        ('C','Area2','BB','C','C','C'),
        ('E','Area1','CC','A B D E','A B','D E'),
        ('F','Area3','BB','F G','G','F')
        ]

all_df = pd.DataFrame(data = all_data_set, columns = ['Name','Area','Type','Group','AA members','CC members'])

 Name   Area Type    Group AA members CC members
0    A  Area1   AA  A B D E        A B        D E
1    B  Area1   AA  A B D E        A B        D E
2    C  Area2   BB        C          C          C
3    E  Area1   CC  A B D E        A B        D E
4    F  Area3   BB      F G          G          F
```

The last row (row 4) is in correct.
Anything that is type BB should only have itself (F) in `Group` `AA members` `CC members`

So it should look like this:

```
4    F  Area3   BB        F          F          F
```

Todo this I was trying to:

1. check when Type is `BB` and Length of `Group` is = 2 items like this:

   `df = (all_data_set.loc[(all_data_set['Type']== 'BB')]['Group'].str.split().str.len() == 2)`
2. Then Iterate over every row and to find the cases like this
3. make a new Df with all the drop rows and make the Group , AA members, CC members = Name
4. Drop the row where that happens in `all_df`
5. Merge `3.` back in to `all_df`

Is there a better pandas way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```py
# identify rows where Type is BB
m = all_df['Type'] == 'BB'
# for Type BB rows, replace Group, AA members and CC members values by Name
all_df.loc[m, ['Group', 'AA members', 'CC members']] = all_df.loc[m, 'Name']
print(all_df)
```

```
  Name   Area Type    Group AA members CC members
0    A  Area1   AA  A B D E        A B        D E
1    B  Area1   AA  A B D E        A B        D E
2    C  Area2   BB        C          C          C
3    E  Area1   CC  A B D E        A B        D E
4    F  Area3   BB        F          F          F
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `iloc` and for loop.

```
for row in all_df.index:
    if all_df.iloc[row,2] == "BB":
        all_df.iloc[row,3:] = all_df["Name"][row]
        
all_df

  Name   Area Type    Group AA members CC members
0    A  Area1   AA  A B D E        A B        D E
1    B  Area1   AA  A B D E        A B        D E
2    C  Area2   BB        C          C          C
3    E  Area1   CC  A B D E        A B        D E
4    F  Area3   BB        F          F          F
```

Comment: I only picked the other one as an answer because it didnt have a loop. But this is super cool too. Can you explain how `all_df.iloc[row,3:] ` works? Is it sayin from column 3 and on wards ?

Comment: No problem, as long as it solves your problem, it's always a good answer :D and yes, in fact, the values from row 3 till the last column will be replaced (If you are planning to do so). If not, the solution from @not a robot will be a better solution.